# Should the MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS flag be used in UTF-8 conversions with MultiByteToWideChar?

Tags: winapi, unicode, utf-8

When doing conversions from Unicode UTF-8 to Unicode UTF-16 using the Win32 API [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), should the **`MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` flag** be used?

In other words, in case of bad invalid UTF-8 input, which is the best behavior, and why?

1. Make the `MultiByteToWideChar()` call **fail** (using the `MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` flag)
2. Just replace invalid input UTF-8 characters with the [**REPLACEMENT CHARACTER** `U+FFFD`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29#Replacement_character)

Comment: I would think it depends on the application.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I was curious for example from a security perspective. And I'm interested in pros and cons as well.

Comment: depends on how failure is handled.

Comment: @EricBrown: What do you mean? Is it better to have a partially invalid string, or completely fail if the input is partial invalid? What is best e.g. from a security perspective?

Comment: It's up to you what you do. What do you prefer? Don't ask about security without providing context?

Comment: @Mr.C64: Again, it depends on the application. If the application wants to be lenient and can ignore invalid characters (maybe it does not care about errors), then do not use `MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS`, otherwise do. However, `MultiByteToWideChar()` does not have an option to generate `U+FFFD` characters for invalid sequences. It either drops them (XP and earlier) or preserves them (Vista+), so you would have to scan the string manually after `MultiByteToWideChar()` fails.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: It seems to me that, on Vista+, `MultiByteToWideChar()` without `MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` [does generate `U+FFFD` for invalid sequences](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/04/10300670.aspx).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I was simply asking if there was some kind of a **"best practice"** or common advice (just like the best practice for copying raw C strings is to not use `strcpy()`, but instead its _safer_ cousin `strcpy_s()` to avoid buffer overruns, just to make an example). I couldn't imagine such a simple question would have generated such a "debate" in comments.

Comment: The best practice depends on your particular design goals. I think that's why there's a debate. I think if there was a good clear answer then you'd have it by now. I think the onus is on you to clarify your intent a bit more.

Comment: I think my question is clear, and I've clarified enough in the comments. My intent is simply to try writing the best code possible, with the highest level of correctness possible. I was willing to learn something new from those who know better than me about Unicode conversions and security. I expected something like _"you may want to use MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS because is safer, in fact Abc..., or beacuse it is Xyz, etc.", or "it's better not using this flag because Abc..."_. If there is no clear answer to my question (or no one knows), I don't have anything to add.

Comment: You have answered your own question numerous times by now. You refer to input that fails to convert from (assumed) UTF-8 to UTF-16 as invalid input. It is safe to reject invalid input.

Comment: @IInspectable: So, do you think that it's good (safer) to use the `MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` flag, and make the whole function call fail if there is some invalid sequence in the input string? I found several times this flag used, but I'd have appreciated some note from the experts in the field.

Comment: @Mr.C64 You should have been around the computer industry long enough to know that the expert answer to almost *any* question is "It depends".  In particular, it depends on the context of the calling code.  Is it robust to failure results?  (There's a lot of code out there that ignores failures.)  If all the code handles failures well, then I'd lean towards failing.

Comment: After doing some research, I've come to the conclusion that using `MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` is a better option from a security perspective. I've summarized that in an answer. (I'm open to be convinced that I'm wrong on that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` when converting from UTF-8 to UTF-16 seems to be the best thing to do from a **security** perspective, in particular related to the issue of the [ill-formed UTF-8 subsequences](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr36/#Ill-Formed_Subsequences) (as discussed in the *"Unicode Technical Report #36: UNICODE SECURITY CONSIDERATIONS"*):

> ***3.1.1 Ill-Formed Subsequences***
>
> Suppose that a UTF-8 converter is iterating through input UTF-8 bytes, converting to an output character encoding. If the converter encounters an ill-formed UTF-8 sequence it can treat it as an error in a number of different ways, including substituting a character like U+FFFD, SUB, "?", or SPACE. However, it must not consume any valid successor bytes. For example, suppose we have the following sequence:
>
> X = <... 41 **C2** 3E 42 ... >
>
> This sequence overall is ill-formed, because it contains an ill-formed substring, namely the <**C2**> [...]
>
> The UTF-8 converter can stop at the C2 byte, or substitute a character or sequence like U+FFFD and continue. However, it must not consume the 3E byte if it continues. [...]
>
> Consuming a subsequent byte (such as **3E** above) is not only *non-conformant*; **it can lead to security breaches**. [...]

In fact, using the `MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` flag makes the `MultiByteToWideChar()` API **fail** in the presence of invalid UTF-8 sequences, so there is no risk that the subsequent code (e.g. the calling code) may consume bytes following the invalid substring.

Comment: misleading/misunderstood quote: AFAIKT, "consume" in the context of the quoted document means to "swallow". That is, the C2-E3 sequence is an invalid sequence, and when you substitute (or ignore) `C2` you MUST then continue and write 3E to the output stream, you MUST NOT ignore `3E`as well, just because it was part of an invalid sequence.